# Eclipse ADT debugger not helping

Tags: android

Hi I'm a noobie in the world of Java and Android, I'm having a hard time with the debugger, for example I have the following code that is triggered from android:onClick on the xml layout. I know that this code is not working because it is missing the View object in the arguments. But my point is that the debugger (when the app crashes) is not showing me information that is relevant for me to address the problem, it shows "Source not found" as the main message and it does not even show the line number where the problem happened in my code.
What am I doing wrong? is there something I don't know or I'm I looking in the wrong place, please help, Thanks!

```
    public void buttonClicked(){
    textView1.setText("Clicked!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the LogCat?

Comment: From my experience, with other programming languages, the debugger or the environment, will show you at least the line number where a problem is found, or where the execution stops due to a problem. Where is that information in the Android Development Tools environment? All I get is a cryptic "Source not found" error

Answer (score 0):

first, you have to make sure whether you have built the connection between your xml file and your method. check Android reference http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick. In another way, you can use setOnclickListener to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

The code you pasted above is never being executed BECAUSE you're not passing in a View. To use the debugger, you should set a breakpoint on your line textView1.setText("Clicked!");

When the program executes that line, the debugging view will open up in Eclipse.